# Spring Data Mongo: Handling '$' character in field name

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data Mongo 2.1.5.RELEASE to connect my Spring Boot 1.5.15 service to a MongoDB 3.2. The problem with this version of Mongo is that the field property name cannot contain the character `$`: [Restrictions on Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names).

Trying to use a property with such character, I am obtaining the following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 52 (DollarPrefixedFieldName): 'The dollar ($) prefixed field '$NAME' in 'fields.$NAME' is not valid for storage.'
```

Is there a way to instruct the `MappingMongoConverter` to change the character `$` during I/O with the database?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In MongoDB  3.6, this problem is fixed but for nested field only, and you can change column name for only database